# Please tell me the syntax for the following code?

Tags: android, arrays, constructor

```
Class xyz()
  {
        HotelInfo[] b = new HotelInfo[5];
        b[0] = new HotelInfo("PAUL'S CAFE","Laxmi Road");
        b[1] = new HotelInfo("GEORGE","MG Road");
        ...
        ...
  }
```

The error says " Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. Class has to be class (case sensitive)
2. Don't use parentheses in your class declaration
3. Already declared class variables can only be accessed in methods

Try this:

```
class xyz {
    HotelInfo[] b = new HotelInfo[5];

    xyz() {
        b[0] = new HotelInfo("PAUL'S CAFE","Laxmi Road");
        b[1] = new HotelInfo("GEORGE","MG Road");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do this in the class and not in a method, it's normal that you have this error.
You need to set values in a method, like in the constructor.
Understand ?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this outside a method you can do

```
class xyz
{
        HotelInfo[] b = {
            new HotelInfo("PAUL'S CAFE","Laxmi Road"),
            new HotelInfo("GEORGE","MG Road"),
            ....
            new HotelInfo("ANOTHER","the last one")
        };
}
```